# how linux::ext4's block-level read/write work

Tags: c, io, linux-kernel, filesystems, ext4

Im creating a new database, which would work directly on the block-device, without a file-system,

But block-level read/write operations, require higher standards, like

- Aligned-memory,
- Per-block access instead of per-byte, etc

So I decided to either learn from, or maybe fork, the block-level read/write implementation of ext4, the default fs of linux,

NOTE: I cannot use filesystem, because the db's architecture, requires it, to capture the whole needed space, at the db creation, all the tables, heap, indexes, etc are then managed manually by the db itself.

Currently the db use `pread64`/`pwrite64`, for per-byte access,

So I checked the linux's source code, and got to

- [`ssize_t ksys_pread64`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/read_write.c#L652), which calls
- [`ssize_t vfs_read`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/read_write.c#L450), which again calls
- `struct file`'s `f_op`'s `read` function,
- Im not able to find the **definition** of this function, also confused, that where to proceed from here

Also, should I, or not, use the ext4's implementation, like is there any, more efficient implementation of block-access?, Im really confused,

EDIT: I know that `read` block, `memcpy`, `write` block is not hard, but Im in the search, for reducing the `memcpy` overhead, hence achieving efficiency, by only `memcpy`ing `void *unAlignedBytesBefore` and `void *unAlignedBytesAfter`, of the buffer to be written, rest all is written as passed.

thanks

Comment: ext4 (and probably most filesystems) do not have `read` and `write` file operations these days. They have `read_iter` and `write_iter` file operations. There are also address space operations for handling I/O to memory-mapped files. Block-level alignment is only required for "direct I/O" transfers (which you might wish to use in your database). You will probably be better off looking at the operations on raw block devices in "block/fops.c" rather than getting bogged down in file system code.

Comment: @IanAbbott , I checked out "block/fops.c", but saw that linux uses a hard-coded value for block_size, 512, then how can this be compatible with 4K block_size devices?, I know `ioctl` and getting the physical_block_size of the device, but curious, that how can linux get away by hard-coding this , thanks

Comment: I guess if the drive does not support 512 byte logical sectors, the kernel's block layer deals with partial updates of physical sectors. I'm not familiar with the details. Of course, there is nothing stopping an application using its own, stricter alignment.